# How to make a table with many checkboxes

Tags: java, jsf

I have a question regarding selectManyCheckboxes. And by that I mean, **many**. I have in the bean a list of 85 options which I have to display in 4 columns, and every column should have around 25 options. My snipet of code is this:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="groups" value="#{shareOfferBean.selectedGroupIds}" layout="pageDirection" label="#{amsg.groups}"
                                          converter="groupConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{shareOfferBean.groups}" var="g" itemValue="#{g.id}" itemLabel="#{g.name}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

With this, I get only all of the checkboxes in 1 column and 85 rows which is really really ugly on the page. How can I make the rows limited, so they break and go in another column? Thanks to everyone that tries helping!

Comment: how about putting it inside ui:repeat?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that comment? Some kickoff example would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using an UI:repeat to loop through.

```
<ui:repeat var="x" value="#{tableBean.kList}">
   <p:selectManyCheckbox id="groups" value="#{shareOfferBean.selectedGroupIds}" layout="pageDirection" label="#{amsg.groups}"
                                      converter="groupConverter">
<f:selectItems value="#{shareOfferBean.groups}" var="g" itemValue="#{g.id}" itemLabel="#{g.name}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
 </ui:repeat>
```

you could do something like this. i dint test it. you could give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve it. They are normally displayed without the ui:repeat, but the problem is that they are in only one column, not separated in multiple.